Unable to deploy due to Payload Error Invalid version specified on package.xml
I'm unable to deploy a simple LWC from a trailhead. (I'm copy/pasting the example code, couldn't get to the hands-on challenge)
A list of things that I already tried:

Changed the version on the package.xml document and sfdx-project.json document to many values, matching and don't matching between them
Created a whole new playground and VsCode project.
Installed the old version of the Salesforce CLI Integration extension (that was updated today).

And nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!


Could you please add the package.xml here?

Salesforce version 61.0 only fully released yesterday, June 14th, 2024. It's possible that you were simply trying too early. Deploying your package today should work.

I don't know if this will be helpful or not, but I can say that I was having the EXACT same (v 61.0) issue as you and at the same time on June 14.  I tried many of the same solutions that you did, and possibly a few more.  Gave up at 2am.
Rebooted the laptop this am.  Logged into Playground.  Started fresh VS instance.  Authenticated to playground.  And just for kicks I tried to deploy again.  It WORKED!
I hope you have the same good fortune.
Cheers.

I don't know what it was, but I tried again just now and it just worked. Thank you!
